# Bug versus Feature?

Tags: discussion, meta

I found this [blogpost](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/11/thats-not-a-bug-its-a-feature-request.html) ("*That's Not a Bug, It's a Feature Request*") that is of course completely and entirely unrelated to the StackExchange network<sup>1</sup>:

> I wish we could, as an industry, spend less time fighting tooth and
>   nail over definitions, painstakingly placing feedback in the "bug" or
>   "feature request" buckets -- and more time doing something
>   constructive with our users' feedback.

However, SE metas still require users to choose between [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). This doesn't seem to make a whole lot of sense. So please, provide some discussion or at least explanation regarding this.

More interestingly, as can be seen with this post, a bug/feature-request can be a discussion at the same time: Personally, this looks like a bug to me, and it is a feature-request at the same time but I'm okay with a discussion, explaining why the status quo makes sense (despite the aforementioned blog post).

---

<sup>1</sup>: I hope I don't need an irony tag for that statement ...

---

Edit: I'm actually mainly looking for an authoritative answer.

Comment: @Yahoo Answers enthusiast: You kind of edited away one of the core points of this post ...

Comment: The tags were incorrect, your question isn't about a bug or a feature-request (or both ;), but a discussion on the use of the tags.

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast: Well, my point was that this is a *bug* in meta, and at the same time a *request* to resolve this discrepancy. That's why it was tagged [tag:bug] and [tag:feature-request] as well.

Comment: @bitmask: When a bug report includes a suggested fix that avoids the problem by adding a feature, I'd be inclined to use both tags.  But if I had to choose one, I'd choose "bug".

Comment: `I'm actually mainly looking for an authoritative answer.` What would you consider authoritative?

Comment: Explain what that doesn't make sense? That you want these tags to be mutually exclusive? Or to have people not talk how they talk?

Comment: @random: On the one hand, saying that distinguishing bug/feature doesn't make sense (see blog post) and on the other hand being involved in running a site that does just this.

Comment: @bitmask If that's your problem, well, [Jeff is no longer part of Stack Exchange](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/02/farewell-stack-exchange.html). And yes his inability to distinguish between a bug and feature request was one of the reasons we had to let him go...

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast: Judging from -11+1, the community seems to agree with your statement. I still think distinguishing bug-reports and feature-requests doesn't help that much, but well, humans hate change and I have to accept that (democracy is yielding to what most people think is right).

Comment: Yes, and more often than not what most people think is right, actually is.

Comment: A founder's personal blog post doesn't mean they can't change how they feel about something in their vas deferens.

Answer (score 11):

Technically what separates a bug from a feature request is the project's requirements document. If an implemented feature is not behaving as described in the requirements, then it's a bug, but if a feature (or parts of it) doesn't exist in the requirements, then it's a feature request.

On Stack Exchange we (the users) don't have the software's requirements document handy, so I guess it's not unreasonable that there will be some confusion over what's a bug and what's a feature request. However we do have:

- Common sense (*most* of us),
- Experience with the system (*some* of us), and
- A crude requirements document, in the form of existing Meta questions.

Combining the three we can easily (?) separate bugs from features:

- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

  When something is not working as expected, where "expected" can be either common sense (when I click submit, nothing happens), past experience (damn thing used to work, now it doesn't) or a Meta question (as described there, the damn button should produce unicorns, instead all I get is trolls).
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

  When something doesn't exist or when you want to extend existing functionality. Think along the lines of "Hey, wouldn't it be great if we have a button that produced unicorns?". Preferably only used for concrete features, where you've carved out most of the details.
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

  Well, that's for everything else, really. As a rule of thumb, if it's more about humans than software, it's a discussion.

Now let's see some possible combinations:

- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

  Use when you found something broken, and a way to fix it that would introduce something completely new to the system. No, removing a semicolon somewhere in the JavaScript is not a feature request.
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

  I would avoid, but it could be a valid combination for when you have something new in mind but aren't completely certain how it would work. Even then, probably best to only use [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

  No, doesn't really make sense.

Jeff's blog post is interesting, but I wouldn't put it amongst our beloved overlord's greatest hits. You are over thinking this, we are just talking about Meta tags, their one and only function is to help categorize Meta's content.

---

**tl;dr**

Use [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) when something's broken, [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) when you're asking for something new and [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) when it's about humans and not software. It's simple really ;)

Comment: No it's not. Read the blog post by Jeff. (other than that, yes, I know what bug-reports and feature-requests are)

Comment: *"instead all I get is trolls"* We can file bug reports about that now? I've got a busy week ahead of me...

Answer (score 3):

A good argument for separating bugs from feature requests is that combining them makes it harder to prioritize fixing problems over adding features. With them separate, it is simple.

According to the tag wiki excerpt, use [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) if "you believe [it] is due to a mistake, malfunction, or programming error." I think that statement is enough to separate the two tags. If you can think of any reasoning for the current functionality to be correct, then it probably is. Also, if you do use the wrong tag, only a quick edit is required to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

In 9 out of 10 cases, it is perfectly reasonable to distinguish between [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

As [Yahoo Answers enthusiast said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130745/162704):

> Use [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) when something's broken [and] [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) when you're asking for something new [...]

The 10th case is when you *think* you discovered a bug, but site is actually behaving like it's supposed to (just different from what you'd want it to).

That's what the moderator tag [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) is for: dismissing bug reports that should have been tagged [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

#### Conclusion:

The line between [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) might be blurry **sometimes**, but that's no reason to merge the tags into one.

Whenever [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) is appropriate, the question has to be dealt with differently: a bug needs to get fixed, a feature request has to get discussed first and requires a decision regarding whether it gets implemented or not.